# MySQL How to set variable result of addtime

Tags: mysql, variables, procedure

I would like to execute following procedure , but not working.

```
BEGIN
    set @val = addtime('09:00:00','00:01:00');
    set @sqlstr = concat("select ",@val);
    prepare stmt from @sqlstr;
    execute stmt;

END
```

Result:
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':01:00' at line 1

This code works fine

```
BEGIN
    set @sqlstr = "select addtime('09:00:00','00:01:00')";
    prepare stmt from @sqlstr;
    execute stmt;

END
```

**Result:**
09:01:00

How can I set to variable result of addtime function?

Answer (score 0):

Saw the below example…

SELECT ADDTIME(‘2008-05-15 13:20:32.50’,’2 1:39:27.50’) as required_datetime;

The above statement will return a time after adding 2 days 1 hr. 39 min. and 27.50 sec. with the datetime 2008-05-15 13:20:32.50.

found this at : http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-addtime-function.php#sthash.Clke2PzK.dpuf